# joining selected columns from multiple tsv files in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, cut

I have a bunch of tab separated text files like the following one

```
"gene_id"   "Pattern1"  "Pattern2"  "Pattern3"  "Pattern4"  "Pattern5"  "MAP"   "PPDE"
"ENSG00000119771.13"    3.11528786599051e-18    2.52650109640992e-13    6.25109524320237e-09    0.345846257420197   0.654153736328455   "Pattern5"  1
"ENSG00000123700.4" 1.75016991626305e-36    3.98804090894939e-19    0.63423772228367    3.8159144080782e-21 0.36576227771633    "Pattern3"  1
"ENSG00000128567.15"    1.10722918612618e-23    7.62691311068806e-07    5.77031364194955e-06    5.13675840911147e-21    0.999993466995047   "Pattern5"  1
"ENSG00000130182.6" 9.75717082221716e-22    1.27675651077242e-12    0.469972541094369   1.13677117238758e-12    0.530027458903217   "Pattern5"  1
"ENSG00000131914.9" 3.1627489688037e-41 1.00274706758683e-22    0.0578584524816503  6.98718794692175e-22    0.94214154751835    "Pattern5"  1
```

Now I want to join them into one file in the so that I get

```
"gene_id"   "Pattern5"  "Pattern5"  "Pattern5"  "Pattern5"  "Pattern5"
```

where each `Pattern5` column comes from one file.

I tried some stuff with

```
cut -f 6 <file>
```

and

```
paste <file1> <file2> ...
```

but I couldn't combine it correctly.

Thanks for you help!

**UPDATE:**
I try to give you a testable example as input here:

```
<file1>
gene_id Pattern1    Pattern2    Pattern3    Pattern4    Pattern5
ENSG00000119771 1   2   3   4   5
ENSG00000123700 1   2   3   4   5
ENSG00000128567 1   2   3   4   5
ENSG00000130182 1   2   3   4   5
ENSG00000131914 1   2   3   4   5

<file2>         
gene_id Pattern1    Pattern2    Pattern3    Pattern4    Pattern5
ENSG00000119771 6   7   8   9   10
ENSG00000123700 6   7   8   9   10
ENSG00000128567 6   7   8   9   10
ENSG00000130182 6   7   8   9   10
ENSG00000131914 6   7   8   9   10

<file3>             
gene_id Pattern1    Pattern2    Pattern3    Pattern4    Pattern5
ENSG00000119771 11  12  13  14  15
ENSG00000123700 11  12  13  14  15
ENSG00000128567 11  12  13  14  15
ENSG00000130182 11  12  13  14  15
ENSG00000131914 11  12  13  14  15
```

and the desired output would be

```
gene_id Pattern5_file1  Pattern5_file2  Pattern5_file3
ENSG00000119771 5   10  15
ENSG00000123700 5   10  15
ENSG00000128567 5   10  15
ENSG00000130182 5   10  15
ENSG00000131914 5   10  15
```

**UPDATE2:**
I tried the approach of Ed Morton:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } FNR==1{ARGIND++}
{ genes[$1]; val[$1,ARGIND] = $5 }
END {
    for (gene in genes) {
        printf "%s%s", gene, OFS
        for (file=1; file<=ARGIND; file++) {
            printf "%s%s", val[gene,file], (file<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
} ' $files
```

but the output is not in the right format:

```
ENSG00000128567 4   9   14
ENSG00000130182 4   9   14
ENSG00000119771 4   9   14
gene_id Pattern4    Pattern4    Pattern4
ENSG00000131914 4   9   14
ENSG00000123700 4   9   14
```

Comment: also it would be nice to have the filename as the column header in the joined file e.g. 
```"gene_id"  "<file1>"  "<file2>"  "<file3>"  "<file4>"```

Comment: P.P.S. I have many files (~200) so I'm asking for a general solution where I just insert a list of files into the command

Comment: Noticed you tried cut and paste, I didn't see any attempt to sort or correlate. So is column 1 gene_id the exact same for all files? so we don't have to worry about matching rows. So file 1, column 1's 7th row is the same value as column 1 7th row in the 200th file?

Comment: yes, exactly! The rows have all the same sorting.

Comment: You can probably loop over `ARGV` to access the files and get the filename in `awk` checking the first line for a header match and then using conditionals to print the columns. See  http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2014/08/mingle-2-files-with-awk.html
http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2014/11/dynamically-building-awk-statements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
#!/bin/bash

paste file1 file2 file3 | awk -v patternIdx=6 '

function printPattern(idx, isFirstLine) {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { 
        if (i == 1) 
            printf "%s ", $i;
        else if (isFirstLine && i % patternIdx == 0)
            printf "%s_file%d ", $i, i / patternIdx;
        else if (i % patternIdx == 0)
            printf "%d ", $i;
    }
    printf "\n"
} 
{ 
    if (NR == 1)
        printPattern(patternIdx, 1);
    else
        printPattern(patternIdx, 0); 
}'
```

patternIdx is the column index of `Pattern5`

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do 
    cut -f 6 $f; done | 
awk '{if ($1~/Pattern5/) {printf("\n%s\t",$1)} else {printf("%s\t",$1)} };END{print ""}' | 
tail -n +2
```

"Pattern5"  0.654153736328455   0.36576227771633    0.999993466995047
"Pattern5"  0.654153736328455   0.36576227771633    0.999993466995047
"Pattern5"  0.654153736328455   0.36576227771633    0.999993466995047

(i just used the same data for file1-3.)
You can also specify input files, if they are regularly named, with a glob, e.g. `for f in myfiles*`.